# mathura Krushna janmbhumi mandir references

Tags: puranas, krishna, history, temple

mathura Krushna janmbhumi mandir references plz provident me

the krushna mandir in mathura was half destroyed by outsiders.

Can i get some reference from shastras about the ancients temple and place where paramatma was born as a child?
how did it look in the past as per scripture.

with Sri krushna paramatma grace it will be revived along with gyanvapi, so it is important we get many information about our ancient temples.

plz give references for krushna janmbhoomi from puranas and vedas.

Comment: Jail, place where Krishna was born, is in temple or mosque? Keshava Deva temple is original one?

Comment: IN the petition filed in court they say bhagvan is hidden insider the mosque site ground by attackers